# Transform sample to achieve target mean, skewness, etc

Tags: algorithms, sample, skewness, moments

I have a sample of data with *N* values from which I calculate basic moments such as mean, standard deviation and skewness. I will then change these moments to different values according to my own rules, these new values are not based on any existing sample.

I would then like to transform the original sample into another with the same size (*N*) and that best approximates the new target moments. This new sample could be computed from scratch or it could (preferrably) be iteratively constructed based on the sample from which I calculated the original moments.

Is there any known algorithm or method that does this (either doing from scratch or changing an existing sample)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you would have to optimise your own figure-of-merit. Clearly changing any of mean, SD, skewness affects the others. SD must be positive for skewness to be defined; that will be evident to you; but skewness is also bounded as a function of sample size

Comment: See [Boltzmann's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Continuous_version) for one example of such a recipe. Whether it is appropriate for you depends on your objective in making this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to equating (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126414/dealing-with-missing-values-where-the-question-was-not-asked/126418#126418)). In the case of equating you take two variables $X$ and $Y$ (e.g. two tests taken by a single group of students) and transform the distribution of $X$ in such a way that it resembles the distribution of $Y$. If you want to preserve only the first two moments you could use linear equating:

$$ \operatorname{Lin}_Y(x_i) = \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}x_i + \left( \mu_Y - \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}\mu_X \right)  $$

However if you want to be more precise and match the quantiles, then a little bit more advanced method is needed, i.e. equipercentile equating, where you use [cumulative distribution functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and [their inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of $X$ and $Y$:

$$ \operatorname{Equi}_Y(x_i) = F^{-1}_Y \left[ F_X(x_i) \right] $$

So the general idea is that you can find such values $u_i$ that range from $0$ to $1$ that correspond to certain values of $F_X(x_i)$ and then find values of $F_Y(y_i)$ that correspond to those values:

$$ F_X(x_i) = u_i = F_Y(y_i) $$

[image]

Of course this works only for continuous data, so with discrete data you need an additional step - "smoothing" of data. For this purpose [kernel smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother) is often used.

Below you can find an [example of R library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/equate/vignettes/equatevignette.pdf) that implements those methods (`req4` from `example(equate)`). Empirical distribution `x` is transformed to match `y`, where `yx` is the outcome. As you can see, resulting mean, standard deviation, skewness and kurtosis of the outcome are close to the target.

```
Equipercentile Equating: rx to ry 

Design: equivalent groups 

Smoothing Method: loglinear presmoothing 

Summary Statistics:
    mean   sd skew kurt  min   max    n
x  19.85 8.21 0.38 2.30 1.00 40.00 4329
y  18.98 8.94 0.35 2.15 1.00 40.00 4152
yx 18.98 8.99 0.35 2.21 0.01 40.05 4329
```

Comment: How does this work with mean, SD, skewness?

Comment: I see why the percentile-equating method might give a starting approximation to a solution, but I do not understand why it should match moments.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I will study these examples. Skewness is of special importance to me, I might even be able to ignore changes to mean and sd and focus solely on achieving a sample with the target skewness.

Comment: If you can get to the skewness you desire, getting to the desired standard deviation and mean are trivial from there; simply standardize (which doesn't change the skewness) and then multiply by the desired standard deviation and add the desired mean.