# How does the inverse transform method work?

Tags: r, distributions, inference, random-generation, quantiles

How does the inversion method work?
Say I have a random sample $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ with density $f(x;\theta)={1\over \theta} x^{(1-\theta)\over \theta}$ over
$0<x<1$ and therefore with cdf $F_X(x)=x^{1/\theta}$ on $(0,1)$.  Then by the inversion method I get the distribution of $X$ as $F_X^{-1}(u)=u^\theta$.

So does $u^\theta$ has the distribution of $X$?  Is this how the inversion method works?

```
u<-runif(n)
x<-u^(theta)
```

Comment: See our threads on the [probability integral transform](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform).

Comment: Yes, although it's usually called the "probability integral transform."  Try deriving the distribution function of $F^{-1}(U)$ to see why it works.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The method is very simple, so I'll describe it in simple words. First, take [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $F_X$ of some distribution that you want to sample from. The function takes as input some value $x$ and tells you what is the probability of obtaining $X \leq x$. So

$$ F_X(x) = \Pr(X \leq x) = p $$

[inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of such function function, $F_X^{-1}$ would take $p$ as input and return $x$. Notice that $p$'s [are uniformly distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165239/how-are-percentiles-distributed/165240#165240) -- this could be used for sampling from any $F_X$ if you know $F_X^{-1}$. The method is called the [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). The idea is very simple: it is easy to sample values uniformly from $U(0, 1)$, so if you want to sample from some $F_X$, just take values $u \sim U(0, 1)$ and pass $u$ through $F_X^{-1}$ to obtain $x$'s

$$ F_X^{-1}(u) = x $$

or in R (for normal distribution)

```
U <- runif(1e6)
X <- qnorm(U)
```

To visualize it look at CDF below, generally, we think of distributions in terms of looking at $y$-axis for probabilities of values from $x$-axis. With this sampling method we do the opposite and start with "probabilities" and use them to pick the values that are related to them. With discrete distributions you treat $U$ as a line from $0$ to $1$ and assign values based on where does some point $u$ lie on this line (e.g. $0$ if $0 \leq u < 0.5$ or $1$ if $0.5 \leq u \leq 1$ for sampling from $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(0.5)$).

[image]

Unfortunately, this is not always possible since not every function has its inverse, e.g. you cannot use this method with bivariate distributions. It also [does not have to be the most efficient method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/132586/35989) in all situations, in many cases better algorithms exist.

You also ask what is the distribution of $F_X^{-1}(u)$. Since $F_X^{-1}$ is an inverse of $F_X$, then $F_X(F_X^{-1}(u)) = u$ and $F_X^{-1}(F_X(x)) = x$, so yes, values obtained using such method have the same distribution as $X$. You can check this by a simple simulation

```
U <- runif(1e6)
all.equal(pnorm(qnorm(U)), U)
```

Comment: Good answer. This method works when you have distributions such as **exponential, Cauchy, Geometric, Pareto, Logistic, Extreme Value Weibull**, etc. For example you can not find a closed form for a **normal distribution**. Therefore you will not be able to use this method. You could try other methods such as **Rejection Method**.

Comment: You can use the inverse transform method with the normal distribution. There are numerous implementations out there for the [normal inverse CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function). For example, you can write normal inverse CDF using the [complementary error function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/erfc). An example implementation of [erfc is here](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/doxygen/erf_8C-source.html). Don't code erfc yourself; use a library. That no closed form formula exists does *not* imply that you cannot use high quality numerical approximations.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $U^θ$ has the distribution of $X$.

Two additional points on the intuition behind inverse transform method might be useful

(1) In order to understand what $F^{-1}$ actually means please refer to a graph in Tim's answer to [Help me understand the quantile (inverse CDF) function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212813/help-me-understand-the-quantile-inverse-cdf-function)

(2) [Please, simply ignore the following, if it brings more confusion instead of clarity]

Let $X$ be any random variable (r.v.) with continuous and strictly increasing cdf $F$. Then $$F(X) \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$$
Note on notation: $X$ is a r.v. Therefore, the function of r.v. $X$, $F(X)$ is a r.v. itself.

For example, if you would flip the question, so that you would have access to $X$ and wanted to generate a standard uniform, then $X^{1/\theta} \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$. Let call this random variable $U$. So 
$$U = X^{1/\theta}$$
Coming back to your question, you have the opposite task: to generate $X$ out of $U$. So, indeed
$$X=U^\theta$$

PS. Alternative names for the method are probability
integral transform, inverse transform sampling, the quantile transformation, and, in some sources, "the fundamental theorem of simulation".