# Sampling from a Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

I am trying to generate samples from a Gaussian distribution, with the sample having a certain probability, but unable to figure out a way.
Eg. I want a sample from $N(0, 1)$ which has a probability of $0.3$.

For context, I am trying approximate inference for a Bayesian network.

For discrete variables, I divide the real line between 0 and 1 at the intervals equal to the value of probability for each of the discrete value.
$P(X=x_0)=0.35$, $P(X=x_1) =0.65$, using random number generator, if the generated number is $\le 0.35$, $X$ is instantiated to $x_0$ else to $x_1$.

Unable to figure out a way to do the same for continuous distribution.

Comment: The meaning of 'sample having a certain probability' is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use a built-in function of your favourite package (R, numpy etc.) to do this. However, I suggest you first make sure you know what you want to sample from or at least restate your wish to sample from "N(0,1) with probability 0.3". N(0,1) is already a parametrised distribution, like the one you described for the discrete case. If you want to do the sampling manually, you would do so by reversing the process. I.e. draw a number from a uniform distribution and then look for which x the CDF of N(0,1) reaches the particular value you have drawn.

I hope that helps clarifying things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

With sampling from continuous distributions, like normal, you can follow exactly the same procedure like in your discrete example. First, using [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $F_X$ you find probability that $X \le x$,

$$ \Pr(X \le x) = F_X(X) $$

and then using [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of cumulative distribution function (so called, [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)) you follow the procedure described by you. So first you sample $U$ that is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and then take

$$ X = F_X^{-1}(U) $$

in your case it is quantile function of standard normal

$$ X = \Phi^{-1}(U) $$

or in R code:

```r
U <- runif(1000)
X <- qnorm(U)
```

See this thread for more details: [How does the inverse transform method work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337)

There are also other algorithms for sampling from normal distribution, as described, for example, [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution).