# Practical applications of the Laplace and Cauchy distributions

Tags: distributions, density-function, laplace-distribution

I want to know if there are any examples of real-life applications of the Laplace and Cauchy density functions. How do they differ in their applications?

This [related post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33776/119261), however, does not answer my question.

Comment: The Cauchy distribution is the Student's $t$-distribution with $1$ degree of freedom, so if you use *very small* sample sizes (for example $2$) then it may help

Comment: In this work, a cauchy/lorentz distribution was used to remove the noise from a synchrotron CT: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.biomaterials.2008.12.048

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416304/why-is-the-cauchy-distribution-so-useful

Answer (score 6):

One example is using them as [robust priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177210/why-is-laplace-prior-producing-sparse-solutions/177217#177217) for regression parameters, where Laplace prior corresponds to LASSO (Tibshirani, 1996) , but $t$-distribution, or Cauchy are other alternatives (Gelman et al, 2008).

Moreover, you can have [L1 regularized](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior/163413#163413) regression with Laplace errors (i.e. minimizing absolute error).

Another example: [Laplace noise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223494/what-is-meant-by-laplace-noise) is used in currently trendy field of [differential-privacy](/questions/tagged/differential-privacy).

---

Tibshirani, R. (1996). [Regression shrinkage and selection via the lasso.](http://www.gautampendse.com/software/lasso/webpage/Tibshirani1996.pdf) Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological), 267-288.

Gelman, A., Jakulin, A., Pittau, G.M., and Su, Y.-S. (2008). [A weakly informative default prior distribution for logistic and other regression models.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1231424214) The Annals of Applied Statistics, 2(4), 1360-1383.

Comment: Does the Cauchy distribution have practical applications in the study of Brownian motion?

Comment: @StubbornAtom https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_process , my answer does not provide a closed list of all applications since there is much more of them.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, It may be semantics, but Brownian motion in mathematics usually refers to the Wiener process where steps are taken according to a normal distribution (at least to me). When a Cauchy distribution is considered, the resulting process is often called Levy (or Cauchy) flight and has several important applications in biology.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add an interesting case where the Cauchy distribution can arise in Biology.

Imagine you are a shark roaming around a space $A \subset \mathbb R^3$ in search of food, which is represented mathematically by the neighborhoods $N_\epsilon(x_i)$ of several food sources $x_i$.

**Brownian motion** refers to the random walk process of swimming to a new location where the change in each dimension is a normally distributed random variable. If the normal distributions have mean zero, the shark is guaranteed to find a food source *eventually*.

[image: brownian motion]

When food sources are scarce, the shark may abandon Brownian motion in favor of a **Levy flight**, in which the random walk distribution is a Cauchy distribution (or some other heavy tailed distribution). In Levy flight, the shark explores the space in a "greedy" way, sacrificing depth of the search in order to explore the space more quickly.

[image]

This is referred to as the [Levy flight foraging hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight_foraging_hypothesis). The movement of sharks, swordfish, ants, albatross, humans and other species have been shown to be well-modeled by levy flight (compared to traditional Brownian motion) in a wide variety of scenarios (although the evidence is somewhat mixed). In many mathematical settings, Levy flight is demonstrably faster at blindly searching a space and is often used in robotics competitions.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace distribution is also related to median linear regression models. For a model:

$$y_i=x_i^T\beta + \epsilon_i,$$
where $\epsilon_i$ are iid Laplace with location $0$ and scale $\sigma$, the maximum likelihood estimators of $\beta$ coincide with the median regression estimators
$$\hat{\beta} =\text{argmin} \sum_i\vert y_i-x_i^t\beta\vert.$$

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression

The half-Cauchy prior is very popular in Bayesian hierarchical models:

> Nicholas G. Polson and James G. Scott (2012). [On the Half-Cauchy Prior for a Global Scale Parameter](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1354024466). Bayesian Analysis.