# Generating random numbers from normal distribution via inverse uniform distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation, uniform-distribution

I would like to create a random number generator for the normal distribution via using a uniform linear congruential generator (on uniform distribution) and the inversion method.

However, I'm getting stuck at the final state. Please correct my understanding at any point!

Say i have an LCG, which generates numbers from 0 - 1. It follows a uniform distribution of (0,1).

Now, I want my subsequent normal distribution (X) to follow the same range, so it's standard normal, hence i normalize the area

[image]

Now

[image]

Using taylor series as this cannot be integrated, I get

[image]

However, now I'm stuck. even if i integrate this, I cannot invert this to y = f(x) due to the powers of y. Am I even going about this right?

Any help will be much appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Why not simply use inverse transform http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337 ?

Comment: ...I was not aware such a magical function existed, thought I had to figure it out by hand. For curiositys sake, how would i compute this manually?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not a correct implementation of 'the inversion method'. Done correctly, you'd be trying to invert the normal cdf.

Comment: When you say "manually" there what do you mean? With pen and paper?

Comment: Not really, but I guess that works too? Basically i would like to know how to continue from here. The idea is to generate random numbers following a std normal distribution, from an input set of uniformly distributed numbers, via a inverse transform

Comment: Am i not inverting the normal cdf..?

Comment: No, you're not. There's several errors all at once which makes it hard to untangle.

Comment: There's a graphical illustration of the inversion method for the normal case on the Wikipedia page [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). Reading the article may help clarify ideas for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45730/discussion-between-wboy-and-glen-b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sample from any distribution using uniform distribution you can use [inverse transform method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337), so there is no need in re-inventing the wheel. For this you simply need to use inverse cumulative distribution function (also known as quantile function) of [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

$$ F^{-1}(p) = \mu+\sigma\sqrt{2}\,\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2p-1) $$

where $\operatorname{erf}$ is [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), and then take uniformly distributed random variable $U \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0, 1)$ and pass it through the quantile function

$$ X = F^{-1}(U) $$

resulting variable $X$ will follow normal distribution.

Most statistical software would provide you with quantile function for normal distribution already implemented (e.g. `qnorm` in R), but if you need to implement it by hand, you can check the following paper that describes algorithm [that is used in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html):

> Wichura, M. J. (1988) Algorithm AS 241: The percentage points of the
>   normal distribution. Applied Statistics, 37, 477–484.

or simply take a look at [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/nmath/qnorm.c) of R's `qnorm`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :) while that presents an alternative way, is there a way to do this via the method i mentioned? Namely, taking the range of the Uniform distribution, setting the distribution i want (standard norm) and normalizing it, attempting to integrate to get the cdf then invert etc?