# Exponential-like distribution with support [0,1]

Tags: probability, distributions

As the title suggests, is there any named distribution whose support is $[0,1]$ or $(0,1)$ and its p.d.f. curve looks like exponential distribution (monotonically decreasing over the support)?

Comment: You could always consider a truncated exponential distribution. The pdf would be $\lambda e^{-\lambda x} / (1 -e^{-\lambda})$.

Comment: @AlexR: that is actually a good answer. Do you want to post it as such?

Comment: Done. Can‘t make any fancy plots as I‘m on the phone, though.

Comment: Why not just call your support a domain. That way we can use a common language among many mathematical subjects. Just found this -  "the support of a real-valued function f is the subset of the domain containing those elements which are not mapped to zero."

Comment: @john - In probability the support is often defined as the smallest closed set with probability $1$.  This works whether the distribution has a density function or not and whether it is discrete, absolutely continuous, singular or some mixture

Comment: When I saw the question title I immediately assumed (wrongly) you were interested in the memoryless property, not just a monotonically decreasing PDF. This got me wondering, so I have asked a related question, which in a sense is asking "how close to exponential can you make a distribution with support [0, 1]?" -   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488090/how-close-to-being-memoryless-can-you-make-a-distribution-with-finite-support

Comment: One possibility is at :  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432688/exponential-family-definition-appears-vacuous/432766#432766

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want a distrbution that looks identically to the exponential distribution, up to a multiplicative constant, you can use a truncated exponential distribution.

It is defined by restricting the support of an exponential distribution to the interval of interest and then re-normalizing the density to obtain a distribution. Your case would yield

$$f(x) = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{1 - e^{-\lambda}}$$

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kfkvpdlelz

Answer (score 16):

The [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) will work if and only if $\alpha<1$ and $\beta>1$ (one of the two inequalities can be replaced by $\leq$ and $\geq$ if you don't mind a flat PDF at $x=0$ or $x=1$.)

Its PDF is
$$ f(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}, $$
so its derivative is
$$ f'(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha-2}(1-x)^{\beta-2}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\big((\alpha-1)(1-x)-(\beta-1)x\big). $$
For the PDF to be strictly monotonically decreasing for $0<x<1$, we need
$$(\alpha-1)(1-x)-(\beta-1)x=(2-\alpha-\beta)x+\alpha-1<0$$
on this interval. This describes a linear function of $x$, so it has its maximum (which we need to be negative) at either $x=0$ or $x=1$, depending on the sign of the slope $2-\alpha-\beta$. We thus have two cases:

- Case 1: $2-\alpha-\beta<0$, or $\alpha+\beta>2$. Then our linear function has a negative slope and its maximum at $x=0$, with value $\alpha-1$, so we need $\alpha<1$. The parameter combinations $\alpha+\beta>2$ and $\alpha<1$ are shown by the light gray area in the diagram below. (The bold line is $\alpha+\beta=2$.)
- Case 2: $2-\alpha-\beta\geq0$, or $\alpha+\beta\leq2$. Then our linear function has a positive or zero slope and its maximum at $x=1$, with a value of
  $$2-\alpha-\beta+\alpha-1=1-\beta.$$
  We want this to be negative, which is equivalent to $\beta>1$. The parameter combinations of $\alpha+\beta\leq2$ and $\beta>1$ are shown by the dark gray area in the diagram.

[image: beta parameters]

The total area is exactly $\alpha<1$ and $\beta>1$.

Here are a few such beta PDFs:

[image: PDFs]

R code for the plots:

```
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,3),ylim=c(0,3),type="n",xlab="alpha",ylab="beta",las=1)
polygon(c(0,1,1,0),c(2,1,3,3),col="lightgray",border=NA)
polygon(c(0,1,0),c(1,1,2),col="darkgray",border=NA)
lines(c(0,2),c(2,0),lwd=2)

xx <- seq(0,1,.01)
plot(xx,dbeta(xx,shape1=.3,shape2=2),type="l",las=1,xlab="",ylab="")
lines(xx,dbeta(xx,shape1=.7,shape2=1.4))
lines(xx,dbeta(xx,shape1=.3,shape2=1.1))
```

Answer (score 12):

The [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) can have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ set such that it is:

- Monotonically decreasing
- Supported on $[0, 1]$

Have a look at the example on Wikipedia where $\alpha = 1, \, \beta = 3$, for instance.

There are also readily available implementations of beta regression in R (e.g. [`betareg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/index.html)), if that is what you want to use it for.

Comment: I once saw a beta distribution with $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$, so density $\beta(1-x)^{\beta-1}$ on $(0,1)$, named as a *reversed standard power function distribution*

Answer (score 11):

There are infinitely many functions that can generate a distribution that is monotonically decreasing and has a support [0,1] (by integrating a positive function adding an integration constant and properly normalizing)

You are looking for a *named* distribution. That will reduce the options. But you still have many options left and this is a very broad question. (It also becomes unclear because it just depends on how far you go with accepting names, e.g. will ["mixture-of-a-triangle-and-a-uniform-distribution"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384884) be considered as a 'name'?)

The beta distribution is just the tip of the iceberg. For instance, many truncated distributions will work as well (for a subset of the parameters). The *'truncated exponential distribution'* came to my mind the first while reading this question. But something less in intuitive, like a truncated normal distribution (with $\mu<0$), also follows the conditions.

This question is very similar to [Common Continuous Distributions with [0,1] support](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270059/common-continuous-distributions-with-0-1-support) .

You could take a look at [this list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_a_bounded_interval) of probability distributions with supported on a bounded interval on Wikipedia. Not all of those distributions will work, but quite some will work with suitable limits of the parameters.

---

Since there are many options. If you are looking for some distribution to use in a particular problem, then you will need additional conditions/context/requirements in order to be able to make a choice.