# Efficiently sampling a thresholded Beta distribution

Tags: random-generation, beta-distribution, truncation

How should I efficiently sample from the following distribution?

$$
x \sim B(\alpha, \beta),\space  x > k
$$

If $k$ is not too big then rejection sampling may be the best approach, but I am not sure how to proceed when $k$ is large. Perhaps there is some asymptotic approximation which can be applied?

Comment: It's not unambiguously clear what you intend there by "$x \sim B(\alpha, \beta),\space  x > k$". Do you mean a [truncated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) beta distribution (truncated on the left at $k$)?

Comment: @Glen_b exactly.

Comment: For both shape parameters greater than 1 the beta distribution is log-concave, so exponential envelopes can be used for rejection sampling. As to generate untruncated beta variates you're already sampling from truncated exponential distributions (which is easy to do) it should be straightforward to adapt this method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest way, and most general way, that applies to *any* truncated distribution (it can be also generalized to truncation on both sides), is to use [inverse transform sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337). If $F$ is the cumulative distribution of interest, then set $p_0 = F(k)$ and take

$$
U \sim \mathcal{U}(p_0, 1) \\
X = F^{-1}(U)
$$

where $X$ is a sample from $F$ left-truncated at $k$. The quantile function $ F^{-1}$ will map probabilities to samples from $F$. Since we take values of $U$ only from the "area" that matches the values of beta distribution from the non-truncated region, you will sample only those values.

This method is illustrated on the image below where the truncated area is marked by a gray rectangle, points in red are drawn from $\mathcal{U}(p_0, 1)$ distribution and then transformed to $\mathcal{B}(2, 8)$ samples.

[image: Inverse transform sampling from truncated distribution]

Comment: (+1) It's worth remarking that the quantile function isn't so easily evaluated.

Comment: @Scortchi If either a or b are 1 or at least an integer, there is a not so bad form (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function)). And in Python there is `scipy.special.betainc` for the inverse and in R there is `pbeta`.

Comment: @Graipher: I've should've said "cheaply, in general" - it'd be better to avoid Newton-Raphson or other iterative solutions if possible. (BTW it's `qbeta` for the quantile function in R.)

Comment: @Scortchi you are right, but in most cases, for modern-day computers this should not be a major problem. I also recommend this approach since it is directly available in most software and can be generalized to *any* truncated distribution, only if one has access to quantile function.

Comment: Undoubtedly it's good to have an generally applicable, easily implemented method to hand whose run-time doesn't grow with $k$; & for distributions with closed-form quantile functions, e.g. the Weibull, it must be as good as it gets. Nevertheless I suspect $k$ will have to be set to chop off a rather large part of the beta distribution before it beats the efficient rejection-sampling algorithms that are also available in most software & that rely only on calculation of the beta's probability density.

Comment: To give a rough idea, I found using R that sampling 10 million uniform variates and applying the quantile function for a beta distribution (both shape parameters equal to 2) with `qbeta(runif(1e7), 2, 2)` takes about 16 times as long as generating 10 million beta variates with `rbeta(1e7, 2, 2)`. So I'd guess $k$ has to be large enough to remove something like nine-tenths of the beta's probability mass before inverse transform sampling becomes faster.

Comment: @Scortchi thanks for this comparison. Unfortunately I don't have time now to describe in details the rejection sampling and make the comparisons as I would imagine this should be done. Maybe you could extend your comments into an answer?

Comment: You've called my bluff - I don't have much time right now either, so to be honest I was hoping through comments to encourage someone else to make a proper comparison & to perhaps explore alternative approaches. I'll place a bounty on the question - & still perhaps get around to an answer in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 10):

[@Tim's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/274516/17230) shows how inverse transform sampling can be adapted for truncated distributions, freeing run-time of dependency on the threshold $k$. Further efficiencies can be got by avoiding costly numerical evaluation of the beta quantile function & using inverse transform sampling as part of rejection sampling.

The density function of a beta distribution with shape parameters $\alpha$ & $\beta$ doubly truncated at $k_1<k_2$ (for a little more generality) is

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^{(\alpha-1)}(1-x)^{(\beta-1)}}{\operatorname{B}(k2, \alpha, \beta) - \operatorname{B}(k_1, \alpha, \beta)}$$

Take any monotonically increasing part of the density between $x_\mathrm{L}$ & $x_\mathrm{U}$: for $\alpha,\beta>1$ it's log-concave, so you can envelop it with an exponential function drawn at a tangent to any point along it:

$$ g(x) = c \cdot \lambda \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda (x-x_\mathrm{L})}$$

Find $\lambda$ by setting the gradients of the log densities equal

$$ -\lambda = \frac{a-1}{x} - \frac{b-1}{1-x}$$
& find $c$ by working out how much the exponential density needs to be scaled up to meet the density at that point
$$ c = \frac{f(x)}{\lambda\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda(x-x_\mathrm{L})}} $$

[image]

The best envelope for rejection sampling is the one with the smallest area below it. The area is 
$$ A = c \cdot (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda(x_\mathrm{U}-x_\mathrm{L})})$$
Substituting expressions in $x$ for $\lambda$ & $c$, & dropping constant factors gives

$$\begin{align}
Q(x)= & \frac{x^a (1-x)^b}{(a+b-2)x - a+1} \cdot\\
&   \left[\exp\left(\frac{(b-1)(x-x_L)}{1-x} + \frac{x_L (a-1)}{x}  - (a-1)\right) - \right.\\
& \left. \exp\left(\frac{(b-1)(x-x_U)}{1-x} + \frac{x_U(a-1)}{x}  - (a-1)\right)\right]\\
\end{align}$$

Writing the derivative $ \frac{\mathrm{d} Q}{\mathrm{d} x}$ is left as an exercise for readers or their computers. Any root-finding algorithm can then be used to find the $x$ for which $\frac{\mathrm{d} Q}{\mathrm{d} x} = 0$.

The same goes, mutatis mutandis, for monotonically decreasing parts of the density. So the truncated beta distribution can be quite neatly enveloped by two exponential functions, say, one from $k_1$ to the mode & one from the mode to $k_2$, ready for rejection sampling. (For a truncated uniform random variable $U$, $\frac{- \log(1-U)}{\lambda}$ has a truncated exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$.)

[image]

The beauty of this approach is that all the hard work's in the set up. Once the envelope function's defined, the normalizing constant for the truncated beta density calculated, all that's left is to generate uniform random variates, & perform on them a few simple arithmetical operations, logs & powers, & comparisons. Tightening the envelope function—with horizontal lines or more exponential curves—can of course reduce the number of rejections.

Comment: +1 Nice idea.  Because Beta is approximately normal for modest to large values of its parameters, depending on how close to each other they are, using a Gaussian envelope might be quite a bit more efficient yet.

Comment: @whuber: I wanted a distribution with a closed-form quantile distribution for the envelope, but I suppose you could generate the truncated Gaussian variates efficiently using one of those good approximations to the Gaussian quantile function. I'm still interested in what you'd do when $\alpha<1$ or $\beta<1$.

Comment: For such small $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you would want to switch to an exponential tail.  I'm unsure what you mean by "closed-form," though: when you look hard at computer implementations of exponentials, Gaussians, hypergeometric functions, etc--that is, all the non-algebraic functions--you discover that none of them have a general "closed form": they are computed through successive approximations such as Taylor series, partial fractions, or asymptotic expansions. There's not much difference between computing an exponential and computing a Gaussian quantile.

Comment: @whuber: (1) The approach I've taken here to constructing envelopes wouldn't work because the densities aren't log-concave. (2) (a) I meant certainly algebraic functions + logs & powers, trig. functions if I'd have been asked, & perhaps even gamma functions - I confess I didn't have a precise notion. (b) Point taken - speedy function evaluations aren't confined to those with closed forms.

Comment: Good point about failure of log-concavity.  I suspect a power law distribution ought to make a good envelope for $\alpha\lt 1$ or $\beta \lt 1$.