# How to generate a $\pm 1$ sequence with mean $0.05$?

Tags: distributions, sampling, random-generation

I know how to generate a $\pm 1$ sequence with mean $0$. For example, in Matlab, if I want to generate a $\pm 1$ sequence of length $10000$, it is:

```
2*(rand(1, 10000, 1)<=.5)-1
```

However, how to generate a $\pm 1$ sequence with mean $0.05$, i.e., with $1$ being slightly preferred?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your desired mean is given by equation:

$\frac{N\cdot p - N \cdot (1-p)}{N} = .05$

from which follows that the probability of the `1s` should be `.525`

In Python:

```
x = np.random.choice([-1,1], size=int(1e6), replace = True, p = [.475, .525])
```

Proof:

```
x.mean()
0.050742000000000002
```

1'000 experiments with 1'000'000 samples of 1s and -1s:
[image]

For the sake of completeness (hat tip to @Elvis ):

```
import scipy.stats as st
x = 2*st.binom(1, .525).rvs(1000000) - 1
x.mean()
0.053859999999999998
```

1'000 experiments with 1'000'000 samples of 1s and -1s:

[image]

And finally drawing from uniform distribution, as suggested by @Łukasz Deryło (also, in Python):

```
u = st.uniform(0,1).rvs(1000000)
x = 2*(u<.525) -1
x.mean()
0.049585999999999998
```

1'000 experiments with 1'000'000 samples of 1s and -1s:

[image]

All the three look virtually identical!

**EDIT**

Couple of lines on Central limit theorem and the spread of resulting distributions.

First of all, the draws of means indeed follow Normal Distribution.

Second, @Elvis in his comment to this answer did some nice calculations on the exact spread of the means drawn over 1'000 experiments (circa (0.048;0.052)), 95% confidence interval.

And these are results of the simulations, to confirm his results:

```
mn = []
for _ in range(1000):
    mn.append((2*st.binom(1, .525).rvs(1000000) - 1).mean())
np.percentile(mn, [2.5,97.5])
array([ 0.0480773,  0.0518703])
```

Comment: Nice job. My point with the Bernoulli was to reduce the question to a well known probability distribution ; from an 'implementation' point of view, your answer and Łukasz' were perfect.

Comment: No kidding, yours is most scientific and the best! ;) I was thinking about Binomial distribution for half a second but that was not enough to turn it into -1 and 1's, so I borrowed your solution "as is", thanks!

Comment: $\def\var{\text{var}}$ So with my notations, $\var(Y)= 4\var(X) = 4p(1-p) = 0.9975$, and the standard deviation of $Y$ is $\simeq 0.999$. When you take the mean on $10^6$ samples, the standard deviation is $0.999 \times 10^{-3}$ and 95% of the computed means should be in the interval $0.05 \pm 1.96 \times 0.999 \times 10^{-3}$, that is $(0.048; 0.052)$. Math check out! ;)

Answer (score 12):

A variable with values $-1$ and $1$ is of the form $Y = 2X - 1$ with $X$ a Bernoulli with parameter $p$. Its expected value is $E(Y) = 2 E(X) - 1 = 2p - 1$, so you know how to obtain $p$ (here $p = 0.525$).

In R you can generate Bernoulli variables with `rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = p)`, so for example

```
x <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.525)
y <- 2*x-1
```

Answer (score 5):

Generate $N$ samples uniformly from $[0,1]$, recode numbers lower than 0.525 to 1 and rest to -1.

Then your expected value is

$1 \cdot 0.525 + (-1)\cdot (1-0.525) = 0.525 - 0.475 = 0.05$

I'm not a Matlab user, but I guess it sholud be

```
2*(rand(1, 10000, 1)<=.525)-1
```

Comment: That is a correct way of employing [inverse transform sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337) in here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate more 1s than -1s. Precisely, 5% more 1s because you want your mean to be 0.05. So, you increase the probability of 1s by 2.5% and decrease -1s by 2.5%. In your code it's equivalent to changing `0.5` to `0.525`, i.e. from 50% to 52.5%