# How to find the Inverse Transform of the Gumbel distribution

Tags: quantiles, gumbel-distribution

How does one find the [Inverse Tranform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) of the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution)?

Let $X\sim \text{Gumbel}(\mu,\beta)$ with scale parameter $\beta>0$.

The [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is then $F_X(x)=\text{e}^{-\text{e}^{-(x-\mu)/\beta}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding the inverse transform follows a typical pattern.  Start with the CDF, $F_X(x)$ and set equal to $U$.

Solve $F_X(x) = U$ for $x$.

$$\begin{align} \text{e}^{-\text{e}^{-(X-\mu)/\beta}} &= U\\
-\text{e}^{-\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\beta} \right)} &= \text{ln}(U) \\
-\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\beta} \right) &= \text{ln}(-\text{ln}(U)) \\
X-\mu &= -\beta \,\text{ln}(-\text{ln}(U)) \\
X &= \mu -\beta \,\text{ln}(-\text{ln}(U)) \quad \quad \square
\end{align}$$

When sampling with this method, $U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $X\sim \text{Gumbel}(\mu,\beta)$.

More on the Inverse Transform [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/184325/177387) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

---

```
% MATLAB 2017a
% Code to generate X ~ Gumbel(mu,beta) with inverse transform method
% Parameters
mu = 1;
beta = 2;
n = 1000;                    % number of samples to generate

% Generation
U = rand(n,1);               % U ~ Uniform(0,1)
X = mu - beta*log(-log(U));  % X ~ Gumbel(mu,beta)
```