# Monte Carlo simulation for generating random numbers from a distribution

Tags: sampling, simulation, monte-carlo, random-generation

> Describe Monte Carlo simulation technique and mention its different steps. Also describe **how would you generate random numbers from Weibull distribution with parameters (θ, β)** .

In this question, I know what the Monte Carlo simulation technique is and the procedure to take random numbers out from a random number table to perform  the experiment.
But I have come across many questions which say to generate random number from a certain distribution (here it is Weibull, and sometimes it is exponential); how can I write it in my answer sheet, because I know the command for this in Excel.

Comment: Taking random (Uniform?) numbers out of a table has not been seen for many years!

Comment: The Weibull distribution has a simple and invertible CDF (as does the exponential distribution), so just take random numbers uniform on $[0,1)$ and apply the inverse of the CDF

Comment: @Xi'an actually I am preparing for a govt exam , and the pattern has been the same for more than 30 years , that's the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking as definition of the Weibull distribution that $X\sim \mathfrak W(k,\lambda)$ iff $(X/\lambda)^k\sim\mathfrak E\text{xp}(1)$, the generation of a Weibull realisation can proceed by

1. generating a Uniform $\mathcal U(0,1)$ realisation $u$ (or selecting one from a table)
2. turning it into an exponential realisation as $$y=-\log u$$
3. turning this exponential realisation into a Weibull realisation as$$x=\lambda y^{1/k}$$

This inverse cdf transform is for instance the one used by R function rweibull.

Answer (score 2):

To "generate random number from a certain distribution" you need

- either a software that does it out-of-the-box, like most of the statistical software,
- or write an algorithm by yourself. The simplest one is [inverse transform sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work/184337#184337) for which you only need to know an inverse of the cumulative distribution function and need to be able to generate values from a standard uniform distribution.