# Distribution of Y from distribution of X

Tags: distributions, density-function

If the PDF of distribution of $x$ is $PDF_X$ and there is a mathematical relationship between $y$ and $x$:

$$y=f(x)$$

is it possible to find $PDF_Y$ ?

If yes, how to calculate it?

Comment: @wolfies what do you mean by closed-form solution?

Comment: No - is not possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a general function $h$, there is no direct formula to get the *pdf* of the random variable $Y=h(X)$ knowing the *pdf* of $X$. There is a formula in case when $h$ is a *differentiable one-to-one mapping* from the range (the *support*, I should say) of $X$ to the range of $Y$. I guess from your question that you don't know this formula, so let me give you the picture and the process to derive it.

Take for example a random variable $X \sim {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and set $Y=\exp(X)$. 
The animation below shows some simulations of $X$ and the corresponding values of $Y$. The density of $X$ is shown in blue and the one of $Y$ is shown in orange in the vertical direction.

[image]

Now the question is: knowing the density $f_{\textrm{blue}}$ of $X$, what is the density $f_{\textrm{orange}}$ of $Y$ ?

Taking a point $y$ in the range of $Y$, the density $f_{\textrm{orange}}$ provides the probability that $Y$ belongs to a small area $\mathrm{d}y$ around $y$ by the formula
$$
\Pr(Y \in \mathrm{d}y) \approx f_{\textrm{orange}}(y)|\mathrm{d}y|
$$
where $|\mathrm{d}y|$ denotes the length of the small interval $\mathrm{d}y$. This probability is the pink area on the figure below.

[image]

The probability $\Pr(Y \in \mathrm{d}y)$ also equals the probability $\Pr(X \in \mathrm{d}x)$, shown by the grey area below the blue curve, where $x=\log(y)$ because of $y=\exp(x)$, and $\mathrm{d}x$ is the small interval around $x$. This probability is given by
$$
\Pr(X \in \mathrm{d}x) \approx f_{\textrm{blue}}(x)|\mathrm{d}x|. 
$$
It is clear that $|\mathrm{d}x| \neq |\mathrm{d}y|$. Remember that these two lengths are very small, hence the green function - let's call it $h$ instead of $\exp$ - is like a segment on the interval $\mathrm{d}x$, and the slope of this segment is the value $h'(x)$ of the derivative of $h$ at $x$. Therefore $|\mathrm{d}y| \approx h'(x)|\mathrm{d}x|$, and we finally get 
$$
\Pr(Y \in \mathrm{d}y) = \Pr(X \in \mathrm{d}x)  \approx f_{\textrm{blue}}(x)\frac{|\mathrm{d}y|}{h'(x)}. 
$$
Expressing the right-hand side in terms of $y=h(x)$ instead of $x=h^{-1}(y)$, this gives 
$$
\Pr(Y \in \mathrm{d}y) \approx f_{\textrm{blue}}\bigl(h^{-1}(y)\bigr)\frac{|\mathrm{d}y|}{h'\bigl(h^{-1}(y)\bigr)}, 
$$
or, because of $\frac{1}{h'\bigl(h^{-1}(y)\bigr)}={(h^{-1})}'(y)$, this can be written 
$$
\Pr(Y \in \mathrm{d}y) \approx {(h^{-1})}'(y)\times f_{\textrm{blue}}\bigl(h^{-1}(y)\bigr)|\mathrm{d}y|.
$$
By identifying this formula by the one defining the density of $Y$:
$$
\Pr(Y \in \mathrm{d}y) \approx f_{\textrm{orange}}(y)|\mathrm{d}y|,
$$
we finally get
$$
\boxed{f_{\textrm{orange}}(y) = {(h^{-1})}'(y)\times f_{\textrm{blue}}\bigl(h^{-1}(y)\bigr)}.
$$
This is the so-called *change of variables formula*.

Be careful about one point: this formula is not correct in general. In my example, the factor $k$ relating $|\mathrm{d}x|$ and $|\mathrm{d}y|$ by the approximative equality $|\mathrm{d}y| \approx k|\mathrm{d}x|$ is $k = h'(x)$ because $h'(x)>0$ in this example ($h$ is increasing), and one has to take $-h'(x)$ if $h'(x) <0$. The general formula includes the absolute value:
$$
\boxed{f_{\textrm{orange}}(y) = \bigl|{(h^{-1})}'(y)\bigr|\times f_{\textrm{blue}}\bigl(h^{-1}(y)\bigr)}.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure that $f$ has to be a one-to-one mapping. If it has more than one inverse, you can sum over the inverses. E.g. see [my answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/188225/12100)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão I just mean I give the formula for the case of a 1-1 mapping. Otherwise I can't say $\Pr(Y \in dy)=\Pr(X \in dx)$.

Comment: Just a follow-up question. Does it mean that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$, then sampling $\widehat{X}$ from X and calculating $Y=f(\widehat{X})$ is always equivalent to sampling $\widehat{Y}$ directly from Y?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ has a standard normal distribution, then pdf of $X$ is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

Suppose the mathematical relationship between the random variable $Y$ and $X$ is $Y=2X$. It will be easy to find the pdf of $Y$.

Basically there are two methods to find the pdf of Y

**1.** use the CDF then take  derivative the CDF.

**2.** Use variable transformation directly (use Jacobian)

I will show the second method here.

$y=2x \Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{2}y$

$J=\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2}$

$f(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{y}{2})^2}|J|=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{8}y^2}$

You can see the pdf of $Y$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{8}y^2}$

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you ask about situation where we have random variable $X$, its density function $f(x)$, and you are interested of finding probability density function of random variable $Y$ defined as $Y = f(X)$.

Such relationship is pretty straightforward for [cumulative distribution function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165239/how-are-percentiles-distributed), but does not have to exist for probability density function. Recall that

> function is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of
>   permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to
>   *exactly one output*. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29), italics added)

and look at the two figures below showing PDF of standard normal $f(x)$. Every $x$-axis value is related to exactly one $y$-axis value (left figure), but some $y$-axis values are related to more than one $x$-axis value (right figure), so the [inverse relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) is not a function. This does not have to be true for all the functions, but only to the ones that are not [one-to-one mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

[image]

If you are interested in probability of observing $f(x)$ values, it can be obtained by simulation. To compute probabilities sample values from random variable $X$ and pass them through density function $f(\cdot)$ the same way as you could make any other transformations of $X$. This enables you to obtain $y=f(x)$ and then compute empirical probabilities for $y$ values. Example of R code for normal distribution is provided below.

```r
hist(dnorm(rnorm(1e5)))
```

[image]

Comment: I think your choice of $f$ is possibly confusing, because it is a *pdf*.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks, I made the wording more clear.

Comment: Tim, I still don't understand. There are two pdf's in the OP, and a transformation $f$. But you take for $f$ a pdf, that's why I said it is confusing. It would be clearer for example if you took $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm under the impression you misread the question, and you are answering to the question of the law of $f(X)$ when $f$ is the density of $X$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent as I understood the question $f$ is is a density function for $X$. Unfortunately OP did not make it clear in his/her question and did not provide any follow-up comments to my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent now I made it clear in my answer how do I understand the question to be clear about it. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I don't think so, because he denotes by $PDF_X$ the pdf of $X$. But as you say, now you made it clear how you understand. It is true that $f$ is a bit  mysterious in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Let's see how.

When $Y = f(X)$, the conditional P(Y|X) can be written as

$$P(Y=y|x) = \delta(y - f(x))$$

where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

The PDF of Y can be obtained by marginalising over X:

$$ P(Y=y) = \int P(y|x) P(x)dx = \int \delta(y - f(x))P(x)dx $$

To compute such integral, we can use [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function)

$$\int h(x)\delta(g(x)) dx = \sum_i \frac{h(x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}$$

where $x_i$ are the roots of $g$. Replacing it in our marginal with $g(x) = y - f(x)$, and $h(x)=P(x)$, we get

$$ P(Y=y) = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{P(x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} $$

where $x_i$ are the solutions of $y = f(x)$.

This is as far as we can go. Nevertheless, this formula evidences that:

- the problem can be treated as any other problem of probability: you define the random variables, the conditional probabilities, and compute the marginal;
- the solution does not necessarily have a closed formula, but it does not require $f$ to be bijective;
- when the function is bijective (single root), this solution reduces to the solution @Stéphane Laurent [gave](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/188210/12100).

I find this solution nice because I don't have to remember it; it is a consequence of the definition of $Y$ and $P(Y|X)$.

Let's take an example: X is uniformly in $x \in [-1/2, 1/2]$, $Y = f(X) = X^2 \in [0, 1/4]$. Compute $P(Y=y)$.

There are two solutions of $y=x^2$ in the interval $x \in [-1/2, 1/2]$: $\{-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y}\}$. Moreover, the derivative of $f(X)$ is $2x$. Using the equation above, we get

$$P(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{2} \frac{P\left(x_{i}\right)}{|f'(x_{i})|} = \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$$

which can be confirmed e.g. in mathematica:

```
Show[{Histogram[
   RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1/2, 1/2}], 100000]^2, 
   Automatic, "PDF"], 
  Plot[1/Sqrt[y], {y, 0.001, 1/4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

If X is uniform in $[0, 1]$ instead, there is only one solution and we get

$$P(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: $\Pr(Y=y)=0$ if $Y$ has a pdf.