# How to derive the (partial) maximum likelihood estimator for a simple autoregressive model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, autoregressive, estimators, unit-root

I am trying to derive two maximum likelihood estimators which I have seen in a statistics book, but I am unable to derive them and would really like some help.
It goes like this:

Consider the simple AR(1) model:
$$X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$
We assume that $\varepsilon_t$ is i.d.d. normally distributed.

Now with $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$ the (partial) maximum likelihood estimator is given by
\begin{equation}
(\hat{\rho}-\rho)=\frac{\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^TX_{t-1}\varepsilon_t}{\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^TX_{t-1}^2}
\end{equation}
It follows that is $|\rho|<1$ then $X_{t-1}\varepsilon_t$ is a martingale difference sequence satisfying the assumptions of the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) for martingale differences. As a result the estimator is consistent, $\hat{\rho}\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}\rho$ and asymptotically normally distributed,
$$\sqrt{T}(\hat{\rho}-\rho)\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}N(0,1-\rho^2)$$
In the case of $\rho=1$ an with $X_0=0$,
$$(\hat{\rho}-1)=\frac{\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}\varepsilon_i\right)\varepsilon_t}{\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{t-1}\varepsilon_i\right)^2}$$

It is these two estimators, I am trying to derive. I have tried doing it by setting up the likelihood-function, deriving it to get the Score vector and then solving for $\rho$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\theta&=&(\rho,\sigma^2)'\\
L(\theta)&=&\prod_{t=1}^T\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(X_t-\rho X_{t-1})^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\\
\log L(\theta)&=&-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{n}{2}\log(\sigma^2)-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{t=1}^T(X_t-\rho X_{t-1})^2\\
S(\theta)&=&\frac{\partial \log L(\theta)}{\partial\rho}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t-1}(X_t-\hat{\rho}X_{t-1})=0\Leftrightarrow\\
\hat{\rho}&=&\frac{\sum_{t=1}^TX_{t-1}X_t}{\sum_{t=1}^T X_{t-1}^2}
\end{eqnarray}

This is of course just the standard MLE/OLS estimator, which are the same for Gaussian distributions.

I don't know how to get the $\epsilon_t$ in the numerator for the first estimator (might have something to do with subtracting the true value of $\rho$?) and I am completely stuck getting the second estimator.
I am not very familiar with martingale difference sequences, but have tried researching it without any luck, but maybe that is the key to the answer.

I hope someone can help me out - thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your likelihood seems to be missing the [Jacobian of the transformation from $\epsilon_t$ to $X_t$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/511402).